# Spark Scala: update dataframe column's value from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

a =

```
+------------+------------+------+
|        Name| Nationality|Salary|
+------------+------------+------+
|    A. Abbas|        Iraq|   €2K|
| A. Abdallah|      France|   €1K|
|A. Abdennour|     Tunisia|  €31K|
```

b =

```
+------------+------------+
|        Name|Salary      |
+------------+------------+
|    A. Abbas|€4K         |
| A. Abdallah|€1K         |
|A. Abdennour|€33K        |
```

the expected updatedDF should look like below:

```
+------------+------------+------+
|        Name| Nationality|Salary|
+------------+------------+------+
|    A. Abbas|        Iraq|   €4K|
| A. Abdallah|      France|   €1K|
|A. Abdennour|     Tunisia|  €33K|
```

I tried in spark scala code like :

```
updatedDF = a.join(b, Seq("Name"), "inner")
updatedDF.show()
```

But I have duplication in my output after doing join. how I can merge between tow data frames with out duplication ?

Comment: Try: `a.join(b, a.Name == b.Name, "inner").show()`
See: https://imgur.com/a/ieICQrg

Comment: There are two Salary columns, so which salary to accept? From DataFrame ‘b’ or the larger of the two?

Comment: I have to get the salary from b. ((I'm trying to update the salary in a with the new value from b))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have duplication, that means name column is not unique. I suggest to try append index column to be used in join, then drop it:

```
    // Add index now...
    a = addColumnIndex(a).withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id)
    println("1- a count: " + a.count())

    // Add index now...
    b = addColumnIndex(b).withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id)
    println("b count: " + b.count())

    def addColumnIndex(df: DataFrame) = {
        spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
            df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
                case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
            },
            StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false)))
    }

    ab = a.join(b, Seq("index", "Name"), "inner").drop(a.col("Salary")).drop(a.col("index"))

    println("3- ab count: " + ab.count())
```

Comment: Could you please check my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690690/how-to-update-a-dataset-row-from-another-dataset-depending-on-indexes ?

Answer (score 2):

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List(("A. Abbas","Iraq","2K"),("A. Abdallah","France","1K"),("A. Abdennour","Tunisia","31K"))).toDF("Name","Nationality","Salary")
val b = sc.parallelize(List(("A. Abbas","4K"),("A. Abdallah","1K"),("A. Abdennour","33K"))).toDF("Name","Salary")
b.join(a,Seq("Name"),"inner").drop(a.col("Salary")).show
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion here, but still I got duplication.