# How to update a dataset row from another dataset depending on indexes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to update rows of one dataset with rows of another based on indexes of these rows, these indexes are specified along the code, and i have the following code which works :

```
for (int j = 0; j < dFInitIdx.count(); j++) {
            dFIdx = dFIdxCopy;
            addedInt = relationWithMarkets(j);
            if (addedInt < n) {
                for (String colName : dFInitIdx.columns())
                    if (colName != "id")
                        dFIdx = dFIdx.where(col("id").equalTo(addedInt )).withColumn(colName, dFInitIdx.where(col("id").equalTo(j)).col(colName));
               
                listRows.add(dFIdx);

            }
        }
        for (Dataset<Row> rowDs : listRows) {
            dFIdxCopy = dFIdxCopy.where(col("id").notEqual(rowDs.select("id").first().getLong(0)));
            dFIdxCopy = dFIdxCopy.union(rowDs);
        }
```

Basically what this code does is if you have two datasets and two row indexes then it will update the row at the first index of the first dataset with the row at the second index of the second dataset, following is an example :

```
 1) +---+--------+---------+
    | id| Market |   Food  |
    +---+--------+---------+
    |  1|     A  |     S   |
    |  2|     E  |     B   |
    |  3|     B  |     C   |
    +---+--------+---------+
    
2)  +---+--------+---------+
    | id| Market |   Food  |
    +---+--------+---------+
    |  1|     S  |     O   |
    |  2|     E  |     I   |
    |  3|     N  |     P   |
    +---+--------+---------+
```

Then if the first index (`addedInt` in the code) of the first dataset (`dFIdx` in the code)  is `1` and the second index (`j` in the code) of dataset 2 (`dFInitIdx` in the code) is `3` then the resulting dataset would be :

```
    +---+--------+---------+
    | id| Market |   Food  |
    +---+--------+---------+
    |  1|     A  |     S   |
    |  2|     E  |     B   |
    |  3|     N  |     P   |
    +---+--------+---------+
```

My question is : is it a good way of doing it through `listRows.add(dFIdx);` especially if the dataset is large, else could somebody propose a solution with `map()` or other native spark methods (not `join` though)
PS : i tried also using the function `when` on the `id` column to check the current index but it yields an attribute error.
Thanks.

Comment: Are the `id`s on both DataFrames unique for all the rows, or could there be duplicates between rows of the same DataFrame?

Comment: the ids are unique within one dataset, no row duplicates.